# Selenium Java not persisting final modifications with --headless option

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, headless

I am experimenting a very rare behaviour trying to log in/out from an account in a particular service.

The specific problem is related to the "--headless" option, it works perfectly fine without it. The workflow is the following:

1. Access the login page, enter email and password and click the "In" button
2. Wait for the home screen to load
3. Once in the home screen, look for a "Log in" or "Log out" button
4. Click the button found in the previous point and check that the button was really modified ("Log in" should change to "Log out" and viceversa). This is the confirmation to really know that the action was performed.

What's driving me crazy is that I cannot see any errors during the execution of the program, in both situations (with and without --headless option) my log shows the exact same data (check code at the bottom). For example for a "Log out" request:

- 2021-02-24 10:42:18.358 [main] INFO - loading web...
- 2021-02-24 10:42:20.286 [main] INFO - web loaded
- 2021-02-24 10:42:20.286 [main] INFO - waiting for the home screen
- 2021-02-24 10:42:22.557 [main] INFO - progress bar detected
- 2021-02-24 10:42:24.585 [main] INFO - Log out request
- 2021-02-24 10:42:24.705 [main] INFO - Log out DONE
- 2021-02-24 10:42:25.281 [main] INFO - [END] Sign in/out request finished

Everything seems to work smoothly in both cases but after running this code with --headless, if I manually access my account I can see that I was not logged out. However without --headless it works perfectly fine.

I played with multiple ChromeOptions at the beginning but none of them works, it doesn't make sense to me that I am detecting the modification of the "Log out" button to the "Log in" button but the action is not really taking place.

Here is what I am using:

- Chromedriver 88
- Java 1.8
- Java Selenium 3.141.59

Here is the complete code:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        int actionToDo = -1;
        
        log.info("[START] New in/out request for user " + username);
        
        // Webdriver configuration
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.put("geolocation", true); 
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("no-sandbox");
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",WoffuUtils.WEBDRIVER_PATH);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        // Waiting times
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(GENERAL_WAITING_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, GENERAL_WAITING_TIME);

        log.info("loading web...");
        driver.get(WoffuUtils.URL);
        log.info("web loaded");
        
        // Log in
        log.info("waiting for the home screen");
        WebElement emailInput = driver.findElement(By.id("tuEmail"));
        WebElement passwordInput = driver.findElement(By.id("tuPassword"));
        emailInput.sendKeys(username);
        passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"intro\"]/div/form/span/button")).click();
        
        // Wait until the home page is loaded
        wait.until(myDriver -> driver.findElement(By.className("progress-bar")));   
        log.info("progress bar detected");
        
        // Identify if we shoud login in or log out
        WebElement inOutButton = null;
        
        // Introduce a short sleep time because the home screen seems to show the "In" button
        // always even when you are already logged in. The "in" is properly replaced by the
        // "out" button almost immediately but without this short waiting time the action is
        // always detected as "Log in"
        Thread.sleep(HOME_SCREEN_SLEEP_TIME_MILLIS);
        
        try {
            inOutButton = driver.findElement(By.id("in"));
            actionToDo = WoffuUtils.ACTION_LOG_IN;
            log.info("Log in request");
        } catch (NoSuchElementException noElementExcIn) {
            try {
                inOutButton = driver.findElement(By.id("out"));
                actionToDo = WoffuUtils.ACTION_LOG_OUT;
                log.info("Log out request");
            } catch (NoSuchElementException noElementExcOut) { }
        }   
        
        // Perform the final click on the appropriate button
        switch (actionToDo) {
            case WoffuUtils.ACTION_LOG_IN:
                inOutButton.click();
                wait.until(myDriver -> driver.findElement(By.id("out")));
                log.info("Log in DONE");
                break;
            case WoffuUtils.ACTION_LOG_OUT:
                inOutButton.click();
                wait.until(myDriver -> driver.findElement(By.id("in")));
                log.info("Log out DONE");
                break;
            default:
                log.error("ERROR: LOG IN/OUT BUTTON NOT DETECTED !!!");
        }

        driver.quit();
        
        log.info("[END] Log in/out request finished");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("ERROR in Selenium in/out handler: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        // Remove the request from the pending list
        String requestToRemove = this.username + WoffuUtils.REQUEST_SEPARATOR + this.password;
        WoffuUtils.pendingRequests.remove(requestToRemove);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was the lack of geolocation permissions when running in headless mode. I upgraded selenium to the latest version available (4.0.0-beta-1) and the next code snippet made the trick:

```
    // Geolocation must be enabled 
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    ja.add("geolocation");
    jsonObject.put("permissions", ja);
    driver.executeCdpCommand("Browser.grantPermissions", jsonObject);
    
    jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("latitude", 1); // desired latitude
    jsonObject.put("longitude", 1); // desired longitude
    jsonObject.put("accuracy", 100);
    driver.executeCdpCommand("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", jsonObject);
```